# How to implement a P13nCoumnPanel in a Grid Table?

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to build a `sap.m.P13nDialog` on top of a `sap.ui.table.Table`, as close as possible as the one provided out-of-the-box by the `sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable`.
I managed to have `sap.m.P13nFilterPanel`, `sap.m.P13nGroupPanel` and `sap.m.P13nSortPanel` up and running but no luck with `sap.m.P13nColumnsPanel`.

I can't really understand how to reflect the columns personalization (e.g. a change in columns order/visibility) performed by the user on the actual table once he/she presses "OK" in the P13n panel.
The example provided in the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.P13nDialog/sample/sap.m.sample.P13nDialog) is very poor and lacks of this last fundamental step.
Can anyone provide some help?
Thanks